# Argument of type '(id: any, title: any, body: any, image: any) => Element' is not assignable to parameter of type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, view, react-hooks

I am a new learner of React-Native. I am trying to map data into View. Have been trying to solve this, read through the documentation and other resources but couldn't succeed. What Am I doing wrong here?

**DATA**

```
const data = [
  {
    id: "1",
    title: "Online Appointment",
    body: "Select the specialist and make an appointment through our App!",
    image: "../../../assets/images/intro1.png",
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    title: "Emergency Call",
    body: "Just In One Click Our Quick Response Team Will Provide You First Aid!",
    image: "../../../assets/images/intro2.png",
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    title: "Online Pharmacy",
    body: "You Can Buy and Sell Medical Equipments Through Our App!",
    image: "../../../assets/images/intro3.png",
  },
]
```

I am using these data to map here:

```
          {data.map((id, title, body, image) => {
            return (
              <View style={TOPCOLUMN} key={id}>
                <ImageBackground source={{ uri: image }} style={INTROIMAGE}>
                  <Text style={TITLE}>{title}</Text>
                  <Text style={CONTENT}>{body}</Text>
                </ImageBackground>
              </View>
            )
          })}
```

**The error I am getting**

```
Argument of type '(id: any, title: any, body: any, image: any) => Element' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: { id: string; title: string; body: string; image: string; }, index: number, array: { id: string; title: string; body: string; image: string; }[]) => Element'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you forgot to destruct

```
          {data.map((id, title, body, image) => {
```

should be

```
          {data.map(({id, title, body, image}) => {
```

Comment: such a dumb mistake to make. thanks

Comment: it happens sometimes xD